# Sculpting brush tool only makes fancy triangles, no depth

Tags: sculpting

So I want to sculpt on that object I have made, and when I do so, practicaly nothing happens. And then I try with a new project, with the original cube, and the factory settings but still nothing happens. I have dynamic topology enabled, and so when I get into wireframe mode, I can see the fancy triangle, but no depth to them, the brush tool only ads triangle... so if you have any idea of what's going on feel free

[sculpt tool http://imageshack.com/a/img600/3905/by1v.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img600/3905/by1v.jpg)

Comment: Hmm.. That is very strange. Do you think you could upload a .blend where this occurs? Then we can determine if it's a setting or a bug.

Comment: Do you have any modifiers on your cube? I was just doing some sculpting and I created a cube, then put a subsurf modifier on it, and then tried to start sculpting. Nothing moved. I had to apply the subsurf before I could sculpt. I hope this is relevant info.

Comment: @AdamMasters This is because the geometry generated by the subserf modifier is not used when sculpting, you must either apply it or use the *Multiresolution* modifier instead. You will note that if you sculpt on the corners of the cube they will move a little bit. This does not apply to dynamic topology because modifiers will not affect the object in sculpt mode when dyntopo is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it works fine, I didn't change anything, I guess it was some sort of bug. I've had to close the program since the bug occured obviously so I can't provide any sort of example file, if it happens again I'll save it and send it back to you. Anyway thanks for the support!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the [*Strength*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Sculpt_Mode#Sculpt_Properties_Panel) is set very low.

Try setting it to a higher value:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, the link was broken.